# In Apache: does the section <Directory "/some/resource/x"> only applies for directories or for URIs as well?

Tags: apache, security, http, rest, authorization

I'd like to know if with the  section I can restrict the access to certain URI (not a dir).

I need to restrict the access of a specific URI to certain users, while certain others could perfectly access the URI. I'd like to know this in order to achieve authorization to a specific resource (resource in the context of an app with REST Architectural style).

If the  can be used this way I could use the authorization modules within Apache to restrict access to URIs.